# Surface identification of hexagon with some edges identified.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, non-orientable-surfaces

I'm trying to identify the surface $M$ constructed by gluing edges of the hexagon as shown below.

[image]

I want to take the orientability/Euler characteristic approach, but what is the general strategy when not all edges are identified?

My thought was to "straighten out" the two unidentified edges into one new edge, say $c,$ to get a pentagon with the gluing scheme $ba^{-1}a^{-1}bc.$ Then this surface is nonorientable with $$\chi(M)=V+F-E=1+1-3=-1,$$so this is a two-times connected sum of projective planes.

Is this right? If not, I would appreciate guidance as to how to fix my answer, and a general strategy to surface identification when not all edges of a polygon are included.

Thank you.

Comment: Ummm... where does the vertex at the upper left map to?

Comment: Would it map to the leftmost vertex? This schematic is confusing to me in terms of which edges we can reduce.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be mapped to the upper-right vertex?

Comment: I think this is gluing ends up identifying all three vertices attached to an edge labeled "$a$"

Comment: @MRKSRC Where did you get this figure?  Are you sure it is correct or even a valid candidate for a figure?

Comment: This figure is from a previous comprehensive exam that I am studying for. That's not to say that there may have been an error, but this is screenshotted directly from the exam.

Comment: Hmmm... I think it is an error, and certainly too hard to put on a timed exam.  But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Interesting. Assuming that this is an error, if this error were not there (there was just some other identification of 4 edges, say abab), would my general strategy be correct? Could we take the 2 unidentified edges and straighten them to some edge c and identify a pentagon by gluing as I originally stated?

Comment: It is fine to combine the two adjacent unlabelled edges to a single unlabelled edge. I don't see anything wrong with the figure.

Comment: $\chi=-1$ is right, but the unlabelled edge means there's a hole, so it's not just a sum of projective planes.

Comment: It's the connected sum of two projective planes and a disk. In other words, it's a Klein bottle with a hole.

Comment: See Chapter 4 of http://www.coopersnotes.net/third_topology.html for a thorough discussion of the strategy, including how to count the holes.

Comment: Have you had a look at that link?

Comment: It's not polite, MRKSRC, to ask a question and then disappear.